Can't jump in UPBGE 0.36.1
I started using UPBGE 0.36.1 and created a walking script in python. But it can't jump. Please can someone help me?
Here is my code:
import bge

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    obj = cont.owner

    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard
    move_speed = 0.2  # Rychlost pohybu kostky
    jump_initial_velocity = 0.4  # Počáteční rychlost při skoku
    gravity = -0.2  # Gravitační síla (nižší hodnota pro plynulejší padání)

    max_jump_height = 2.0  # Maximální dosažená výška (proti gravitaci)
    jump_velocity = 0  # Aktuální rychlost při skoku

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.UPARROWKEY]:
        obj.applyMovement([0, move_speed, 0], True)
    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.DOWNARROWKEY]:
        obj.applyMovement([0, -move_speed, 0], True)
    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.LEFTARROWKEY]:
        obj.applyMovement([-move_speed, 0, 0], True)
    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.RIGHTARROWKEY]:
        obj.applyMovement([move_speed, 0, 0], True)

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED == keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY]:
        bge.types.KX_CharacterWrapper.jump(bge.constraints.getCharacter(obj))

main()

My settings of player are: rigid body with dynamic physics type
And for ground, I have collision with static type.

Although there is still a game-engine tag here, very few people actually use UPBGE here as the game engine was removed from native Blender several years ago. Try asking on one of the other UPbge community forums.
